# Sign In user function from documentation doesn't work Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I had some troubles with the SignInWithEmailAndPassword Firebase method.
When a non registered user tries to signIn (he should create a new user before) Firebase, rightly, throw an error but the problem is that this error freezes my app so I need to catch it but I don't know why also when I catch the error (or at least I think I caught it) the app freezes so I opened the documentation and found this code :

```
try {
  UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: "barry.allen@example.com",
    password: "SuperSecretPassword!"
  );
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
    print('No user found for that email.');
  } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
    print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
  }
}
```

Well I copy-pasted it to see if the error handling works fine because obviously this call will throw an error but also this freezes my app. The I tried to read the [doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/) and I found that the "Error Handling" section is missing [missing doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/error-handling).

Someone told me that I "need to learn javascript" well ok maybe I'm missing something but also a common error can be hard to solve for who doesn't know it, so I will write my previous code below to show you :

```
Future<void> submit(
      context, FirebaseAuth authF, String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential =
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        print('No user found for that email.');
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
      } else {
        print(e);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        LogInCupertinoDialogue(context,e);
      } else {
        LogInAndroidDialogue(context,e);
      }
    }
  }
```

This function is called by :

```
Future<void> _submit(Auth auth, FirebaseAuth authF) async {
    //Create Artist and send it to the database
    if (_validateAndSaveForm()) {
      try {
        //await submit(context, authF, emailF, password);
        submit(context, authF, emailF, password);
        //Dovrebbe andare in home page ma per ora va bene così
      } catch (e) {
        if (Platform.isIOS) {
          LogInCupertinoDialogue(context,e);
        } else {
          LogInAndroidDialogue(context,e);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the below code. It has following functions:-

1. signin()
2. signUp()
3. showErrDialog()

   ```
   FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
   final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();


    Future<User> signin(String email, String password, BuildContext context) async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    try {
    UserCredential result =
       await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: email);
      User user = result.user;
     return Future.value(user);
      }   catch (e) {
     print(e.code);
   switch (e.code) {
      case 'ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL':
       showErrDialog(context, e.code);
       break;
     case 'ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD':
       showErrDialog(context, e.code);
       break;
     case 'ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND':
       showErrDialog(context, e.code);
       break;
     case 'ERROR_USER_DISABLED':
       showErrDialog(context, e.code);
       break;
     case 'ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS':
       showErrDialog(context, e.code);
       break;
     case 'ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED':
       showErrDialog(context, e.code);
       break;
   }

    showErrDialog(BuildContext context, String err) {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
     return showDialog(
   context: context,
   child: AlertDialog(
     title: Text("Error"),
     content: Text(err),
     actions: <Widget>[
       OutlineButton(
         onPressed: () {
           Navigator.pop(context);
         },
         child: Text("Ok"),
       ),
     ],
   ),
   );
    }

   Future<User> signUp(
   String email, String password, String eno, BuildContext context) async {
   await Firebase.initializeApp();
   try {
   UserCredential result = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
       email: email, password: email);
   User user = result.user;
   print("user is :" + user.email + " id is :" + user.uid);
   return Future.value(user);
   } catch (error) {
   switch (error.code) {
     case 'ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE':
       showErrDialog(context, "Email Already Exists");
       break;
     case 'ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL':
       showErrDialog(context, "Invalid Email Address");
       break;
     case 'ERROR_WEAK_PASSWORD':
       showErrDialog(context, "Please Choose a stronger password");
       break;
   }
   return Future.value(null);
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: I used your code but this is the result : 
[Exception has occurred] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LihOPzYb00q0cOPzCLXUaE85Q1iuaPxa/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Try to use above function as it is . once you figure out what's wrong in your code replace them.

Comment: Used your exact code, this is the result :
PlatformException (PlatformException(user-not-found, There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.